# Struggling to handle the AuthenticationException in Laravel 11

Tags: laravel, laravel-11

I'm trying to adapt some code from Laravel 10 to Laravel 11. The code customizes the error message when a user is not logged in. However, it's currently redirecting me to the login route, which I don't have declared because I'm working with an API.

The code I'm using is located in the bootstrap folder:

```php
$exceptions->stopIgnoring(AuthenticationException::class);
$exceptions->render(function (Request $request, AuthenticationException $exceptions) {
    return $request->expectsJson()
        ? response()->json(['message' => $exceptions->getMessage()], 401)
        : response()->json(['message' => __('User does not have authenticated'), 'error' => $exceptions->getMessage()], 401);
});
```

But it's not working as expected. I want to modify the default response that Laravel 11 provides for `AuthenticationException`.

Comment: did you alias `AuthenticationException` in your `app.php` file? also why is the Exception not the first argument to the closure to `render`?

Comment: Yes, and use the withExceptions method.

Comment: I am not using aliases, and it is like this because of the tests I was doing, and it is in the withExceptions section of the app file

Comment: then that isn't the correct exception ... namespacing

Comment: The problem is that if that is not the namespace, what is it?